# Odd wind-speed distribution over North Sea

Tags: meteorology

A popular website for observing wind-speed showed the following distribution over the North Sea 2022-02-18 around the same time that storm Eunice was due to hit the UK.

[image]

There is some kind of long thin region extending out from the firth of Forth of relatively low wind-speed.

> **Question**: What is this phenomenon?

Comment: Wind changes typically happen if a front passes by. What you see here should be a warm front. Try comparing temperatures up and downwind.

Answer (score 1):

What you see is the location of the warm front. Across the frontal zone, the wind direction changes relatively quickly, but not unexpected, due to warm advection. What may be more unusual is that you see it this clearly close to the surface in a coarse model product (assuming you are looking at GFS or IFS), but that can be because here the warm front moves over water so you don't see too many effects from the surface.